# Cross pallet methods calling not working

Tags: pallet, rust

I want to update staking_ledger from a custom pallet for migration of data from one chain to another, using method `pallet_staking::Pallet::<T>::update_ledger` but i am getting error that `update_ledger` is a private function, so how can I call a private function in migration pallet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the pallet locally and update the visibility of the update_ledger function from pub (crate) to pub, you can follow these steps:

- Locate the file where the update_ledger function is defined within
  your pallet.
  Change the visibility of the update_ledger function from pub (crate)    to pub. This makes the function publicly accessible
  outside of the    crate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to call a private function unless you use `unsafe` and calculate the function address.

I think you could clone the Substrate repository and change that function to public. Then use [cargo patch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html#using-patch-with-multiple-versions) for this time.